# Построение графика jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток всем.
Есть большой массив данных (пара миллионов вот таких строк):

```
-0,30273438;-0,06835938;
-0,29785156;-0,05371094;
-0,28320313;-0,04882813;
-0,28808594;-0,06347656;
-0,27343750;-0,03417969;
-0,24414063;-0,03906250;
-0,24414063;-0,01464844;
```

Написал такую программку:

```
import csv
with open('202831.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
trash = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
for row in trash:
    print('.'.join(row))
    x.append(float(row[0]))
    y.append(float(row[1]))
```

На выходе получаю большой массив, однако при попытке вытащить от туда данные получаю:

> could not convert string to float: '-0,30273438'

Нужно построить 2 графика `x` и `y` от `t`, где `t` - длинна вектора(?) `x` или `y`. К сожалению, чукча не программист, прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Проблема в том, что float() ожидает точку в качестве разделителя, а не запятую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените все запятые точками:

```
x.append(float(row[0].replace(",", ".")))
y.append(float(row[1].replace(",", ".")))
```

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо большое) А не подскажете еще, как в итоге построить графики от количества отсчетов t? Ругается на x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (1,).....хотя длинна векторов одинаковая

Comment: все, справился, еще раз спасибо)